# Price rule for products with quantity > 0

Tags: price-rules

I want to be able to conditionally apply promo rules to products only with quantity > 0.

I have tried setting Use for Promo Rule Conditions in Storefront Properties to Yes for the attribute `quantity_and_stock_status` at Stores > Attributes > Product, however this only allows control for In Stock and Out of Stock, rather than actual quantity.

Products in store are set to allow backorders by default, so In Stock/Out of Stock doesn't apply in this case. I feel like restricting sales based on quantity should be available as an option.